# How do we add click events dynamically to the customer view of shopify store when public node application is installed in any shopify store

Tags: node.js, shopify

How do we add click events dynamically to the customer view of shopify store and get the product and customer information when only our public node application is installed in any shopify store, without adding js for click events in shopify theme code.

Comment: use assets API to add dynamic JS code when page load in Shopify, this script loaded inside `{{content_for_header}}`

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that you got as far as making a public App for installation in a Shopify store without seeing the ScriptTag asset. With that, you get a callback dynamically installed in a Shopify store without affecting the theme. Perfect for your use case.